# Date readable format php

Tags: php

Hey guys I need help again :D do you guys know how to convert this line of code into a readable format? The format for example is "Oct. 30, 2016"

```
{{ isset($data) ? $data['chalet']->created_at : old('created_at') }}
```

BTW old('created_at') is a data inserted to the "created_at" column on my table.

Comment: which format do u want? what format are u getting?

Comment: And, What is `old('created_at')`?

Comment: old('created_at') is a data inserted to the "created_at" table. The format for example is "Oct. 30, 2016"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: When format is `Oct. 30, 2016` this. Then, which format you want.? Be clear with everything. Don't just simply ask question.

Comment: @RohitS : not necessary.

Comment: date format for which? `$data['chalet']->created_at` or `old('created_at')` or both??

Comment: @devpro: OP should edit his/her question with requirement.

Comment: @devpro that's the whole line. I need both so it will show the exact format I needed

Comment: Which format you need, Sir?

Comment: `date('M, d, Y',strtotime($data['chalet']->created_at))` and `date('M, d, Y',strtotime(old('created_at')))` maybe

Comment: @NanaPartykar indeed..deleted comment but still user has not posted a valid expectation even though 'devpro' has given valid solution

Comment: @devpro you are correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @devpro

```
{{ isset($data) ? date('M. d, Y',strtotime($data['chalet']->created_at)) : date('M, d, Y',strtotime(old('created_at'))) }}
```

Comment: @devpro I'm sorry I just can't upvote your answer awhile ago because I didn't have enough reputation :D